# Spring @MessageMapping("/hello") XML eqivalent

Tags: java, xml, spring, websocket, messaging

I cannot find XML configuration equivalent for bean using @MessageMapping annotation:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    public Greeting greeting(final HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
```

Any help?